# Use Variable for table in Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sqlite, sequelize.js

I was wondering if it was possible to use variables as a table in sequelize, for example:

```
function getColumns(table) {
  let tbColumns = [];
  return db.table.describe() // table here should be the param of getColumns
  .then(result => {
    for(var property in result) {
      tbColumns[property] = result[property].type;
    }
    return tbColumns;
  });
}
```

in this example, my goal is to get the name of each column and his type for the table passed as a parameter.

in the first version of this function, I used a raw query and it was easy to add variables to it (because the query was a string).

but now, the problem is, i have 2 Databases, one MySQL and one SQLite. and the raw query is different in these two database systems, so the specific features of ORM look useful in my case, but i don't know how to use my var "table" as a table in my function above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
return db[table].describe()
```

?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work. 
I got "Cannot read property 'describe' of undefined" (because db[table] don't exist)

Comment: what does ```console.log(Object.keys(db))``` says ?

Comment: I got [ 'table1', 'table2', 'table3', 'sequelize', 'Sequelize' ]

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak to the rest of OP's function, but the suggested convention of `db[tableName].findAll{(` (by responder Loïc) worked for me.